# Can someone briefly explain this platform

Tags: discussion, support

Can someone explain step-by-step how different is meta islam from the islam stack exchange? And how would getting professionals here rather than there change the situation of some people being left unasnwered? I feel like there should be only one islam stack exchange and not some other stack exchage that is saying " we have more professional answerers to your stack exchange's based questions, though we decided to open our own place " because this would lead to the death of one of these stack exchanges at the ond of the day, please explain everything.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There *is* only one "Islam Stack Exchange", and Islam Meta is part of it: It's simply a separate place where we can discuss the *actual site* instead of the topic of Islam. You can read the relevant help page here: [What is "meta"? How does it work?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/help/whats-meta)

In other words, rather than bogging down the main site with a bunch of discussion on site policy or support questions, which really don't have anything to do with Islam, those sorts of questions would be asked on Islam Meta.

Comment: Thanks for explaining, i can't wait to join you all, i'll work hard in shaa Allaah, and keep up the site for us newbies with the help of Allaah in shaa Allaah. Though what is that black diamond trend?

Comment: @SalmaanAl-Faaris Not sure what you mean by "black diamond trend"

Comment: Balck diamond emoji* some of you with high reputation have it also i've been feeling the urge to say you're not the only otaku here for a while

Comment: If you're referring to the diamond at the end of my username, that just indicates that I'm one of the site's appointed moderators: https://islam.stackexchange.com/help/site-moderators

Comment: That must be awesome, but yeah thanks for the answer i don't want to use up your time acting like this is a chat but please tell me how to embed a link in a text such as "chat" where it takes you to the chat site (of the stack exchange whatever it may do etc. Forget it just answeeeer (plz)